# float object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, typeerror

#### Code

```
def entropy_cal(pos,neg):
    entropy_target=  -1 * ((pos)/(pos+neg) * math.log(((pos)/(pos+neg))[2])) + ((neg)/(pos+neg) * math.log(((neg)/(pos+neg))[2]))
    return entropy_target


def preprocessing():
#   print training
    attr_mean = []
    for i in range(0,7):
        attr_mean.append(np.average(training[:,i]))
    neg = 0; pos = 0
    for i in range(9999):
        if training[i,6] == 0:
            neg += 1
        else:
            pos += 1
    entropy_target = entropy_cal(pos, neg)

    return entropy_target, attr_mean
```

#### Error

```
File "q3.py", line 46, in preprocessing
    entropy_target = entropy_cal(pos, neg)

File "q3.py", line 31, in entropy_cal
    return -1 * ((pos)/(pos+neg) * math.log(((pos)/(pos+neg))[2])) + ((neg)/(pos+neg) * math.log(((neg)/(pos+neg))[2]))

TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

#### Question

While returning the variable "entropy_target", it's throwing the above error. Any suggestions?

Comment: you are getting that error from `(pos)/(pos+neg))[2]` same error from `(neg)/(pos+neg))[2]` also. what is the purpose of `[2]`?

Comment: that basically the base of log

Comment: Are you trying to do a log base 2?

Comment: yes  that's  a log base 2 @BillLynch

Comment: What made you think that syntax would denote a log base 2?

Comment: The base is the second argument of [log](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log), though it's more efficient to use log2 if you want base 2. A quotient of two real numbers is not an array.

Comment: Got it resolved! thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for log base 2 is:

```
math.log(pos/(pos+neg), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def entropy_cal(pos,neg):
entropy_target=  -1 * ((pos)/(pos+neg) * math.log(((pos)/(pos+neg))[2])) + ((neg)/(pos+neg) * math.log(((neg)/(pos+neg))[2]))
return entropy_target
```

in the above code, `pos` and `neg` are non-dictionary values. You are trying to do `getitem` for non-dictionary value. that is the reason of error.

Comment: Getitem is valid for plenty of types that are not dictionary (in particular, sequences). float just isn't one of them.

Comment: yes, i agree. i was mentioning that here in this context.

Comment: hey I'm just using them as another variables. Why shouldn't this work?

Comment: so what is the solution here?

Comment: what is the purpose of [2] here?

Comment: that's a log base 2 @KalyanReddy

Comment: then it should be math.log(pos/(pos+neg), 2)